Add segment to Multisite Site URLs
I've got a multisite network setup as subdirectories.
By default WordPress wants the URLs to be something like domain.com/site1 . However, we want the sites to the URL of domain.com/locations/site1.
Currently we're doing this with a lot of rewrites. The issue is sometimes URLs get missed as Wordpress still thinks the site's URL is just domain.com/site1.
How can we permanently change the subsite's URL to have the /locations/ segment? When scouring the web, I see all kinds of plugins that are no longer maintained or solutions that involve sunrise.php, which don't seem to work in my trials.
So is there a way to do this, and if so, how, or are all these solutions I see online just ways of doing the rewrites, but there's no way to permanently change the sites' URLs?
thanks!

I did a quick search and think I found the same things you did because sunrise.php quickly started showing up in the documentation/notes/discussions.  Looks like a permanent option isn't possible other than whatever that sunrise.php version is doing. (https://paulund.co.uk/wordpress-multisite-with-nested-folder-paths)
